# Get base unit of a custom dimension

Tags: python, pint

Say I define a new dimension and define new units along that dimension. In this example, I use currencies and made-up exchange rates, but could be any other custom-made dimension:

```
import pint 
ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
Q_ = ureg.Quantity
import io
ctx_def = io.StringIO("""\
EUR = [currency]
DKK = 0.14 EUR
JPY = 0.01 EUR
USD = 0.9 EUR
GBP = 1.1 EUR
""")
ureg.load_definitions(ctx_def)
```

Here, `EUR` is the base unit, and conversion to this base unit works fine:

```
Q_(42, "JPY").to_base_units()
# returns 0.42 EUR as expected
```

My question is: **Given this unit registry, and given the custom dimension name as input i.e. `"[currency]"`, how do I get the base unit `"EUR"`?**

---

If it's a built-in dimension such as `[mass]`, then I can do this (not elegant, but works):

```
ureg.get_base_units(list(ureg.get_compatible_units("[mass]"))[0])[1]
# returns "kilogram"
```

However, this trick doesn't work for my custom-made dimension `[currency]`:

```
ureg.get_base_units(list(ureg.get_compatible_units("[currency]"))[0])[1]
# raises:
# KeyError: <UnitsContainer({'[currency]': 1})>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to just look up the dimensionality for all contained units and take the first one that matches:

```py
from pint.registry import UnitsContainer

def root_unit(dim):
    uc = UnitsContainer({dim: 1})
    return next(ureg.get_root_units(unit)[1] for unit in ureg if ureg.get_dimensionality(unit) == uc)

print(root_unit('[currency]'))  # EUR
print(root_unit('[mass]'))      # gram
```

Note also that units are mapped to dimensions in the underlying `RegistryCache`, stored as `ureg._cache`. So if you don't mind relying on private members, you can do the lookup there:

```
In [14]: [k for k, v in ureg._cache.dimensionality.items() if v == UnitsContainer({'[currency]': 1})]
Out[14]:
[<ParserHelper(1, {'EUR': 1})>,
 <ParserHelper(1, {'USD': 1})>,
 <ParserHelper(1, {'DKK': 1})>,
 <ParserHelper(1, {'JPY': 1})>,
 <ParserHelper(1, {'GBP': 1})>]
```

In particular, turning `[currency]` into `EUR` amounts to

```py
def root_unit(dim):
    uc = UnitsContainer({dim: 1})
    return next(ureg.get_root_units(k)[1] for k, v in ureg._cache.dimensionality.items() if v == uc)

ureg._build_cache()
print(root_unit('[currency]'))  # EUR
print(root_unit('[mass]'))      # gram
```

This would all be a bit more straightforward if the dimensionality itself were a key in `RegistryCache.root_units` but still, could be worse.

Note the necessary `ureg._build_cache()`, though: The cache is built only *before* you load your definition. A priori, this is fair enough since it's up to `UnitRegistry` itself how it wants to cache its lookup, and it shouldn't be a problem in practice since it only fails because you're loading your own definition, and once you're loading your own definition, well, you already have the information you're looking for in the definition itself!

However, there does seem to be a bug in this case, as the return values of exposed methods end up depending on the registry's internal state:

```py
In [26]: ureg.get_compatible_units('EUR')  # Fails
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError

In [27]: ureg._build_cache()

In [28]: ureg.get_compatible_units('EUR')  # No longer fails
Out[28]: frozenset()
```